# Outlook Add-in Redirect to chrome not open new small outlook window

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Good day,

I have an outlook add-in and its working fine. Now on my taskpane.html i have two a href tags

**main domain** | a href="https://rachmar.com"

**sub domain**  | a href="https://app.rachmar.com"

Now when i clicked the main domain. It will open a small outlook window and load the link but when i clicked the sub domain, it will open my default browser ( chrome )

I want all the links to open on chrome.

I already try everything, from windows.open and etc.

Do you have any advices or links that i can check and study on it.

Thanks

Comment: Which platform are you testing this addin? Are you using AppDomain in your manifest? Refer https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/appdomain?view=common-js-preview

Comment: Its on the live env and yes im using AppDomain in my manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Outlook on Windows / New Outlook on Windows / Outlook Web / Outlook Mac / iOS/Android?
And is there a specific reason you are using window.open()? Can you please try using [displaydialog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/office/office.ui?view=outlook-js-1.4&preserve-view=true#office-office-ui-displaydialogasync-member(1)) instead?

Comment: Im using outlook desktop both mac and windows os, The specific reason that i want to redirect it to a browser, because i have list of products and each product when the user clicks it , it must redirect to browser so see the product. It cannot be done on displaydialog cause the user will login every click of the list of product.

Comment: 0

Is your domain part of AppDomain? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/manifest/appdomains?view=common-js-preview

If it is part of app-domain, it will open in the outlook window. If it is not, it will open in a browser.